# How to join the column data of three Sql table using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have four tables in which i have to join the column Data. I have used Cross join and at the end i get some values being repeated twice or several times. Please help.

The things i have tried in my sql script code is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT dbo.Table3.ID, dbo.Table4.Usertyp, dbo.Table4.reserved, dbo.Table2.Lotnumber, dbo.Table3.Current, dbo.Table3.Reading, dbo.Table1.LoginName, dbo.Table3.Start
FROM     dbo.Table1 CROSS JOIN
                  dbo.Table2 CROSS JOIN
                  dbo.Table3 CROSS JOIN
                  dbo.Table4
GO
```

Then when i execute i get the data entry several times, Am i doing something wrong. Please help.
I needed a ID from Table 3, Usertyp from Table4 first row, reserved from table4, Lotnumber from Table2 first row data. How can i take all serial entry to a new table using four tables data. Thank you.

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]
[image: Table3]
[image: Table4]

The end result is. I wanted the ID from Table 3 and the respective data from the other table columns: The end output should look like, 
[image: Table5]

Comment: First question, why `CROSS JOIN`?  Google what `CROSS JOIN` do.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Clearly there is non-minimal data here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a cross join. Don't do that. That combines every row of every table in every combination. That can get ugly very fast.

The following should help get you there, however, there isn't enough info in what to match your table 4 to. So once you figure that out, you should be able to continue this approach I am listing:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT   dbo.Table3.ID
       , dbo.Table4.Usertyp
       , dbo.Table4.reserved
       , dbo.Table2.Lotnumber
       , dbo.Table3.Current
       , dbo.Table3.Reading
       , dbo.Table1.LoginName
       , dbo.Table3.Start
FROM       dbo.Table3 t3
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t1 on t3.UserID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 on t3.LotID = t2.LotID
INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 ....
GO
```

Comment: The problem is not CROSS JOIN per se. The problem is the lack of conditions. Your INNER JOIN ONs could be changed to CROSS JOINs & a WHERE.

Comment: @DrDoomPDX at first i did the same with INNER JOIN. Since every table has a ID and i am interested in taking just the ID of table 3. The end result is i get the same row data repeated. For example ID 30,31,32.. with the same data for Usertyp, reserved, Lotnumber, Current, Reading, Loginname, Start.

Comment: @user9630935 Thats probably because your table 4 does not have a good key to go against. Its ID is not the same as the others. you cannot match PK to PK that way.

Comment: Also, I just made an edit. I had incorrectly aliased Table2 as t3. That is fixed. But you still need a foreign key in table 4 so that you can join that one to the appropriate table. Also, I would disregard the advice of using a CROSS join with an added where clause. The SQL query optimizer is just going to change that to an inner join behind the scenes. CROSS joins are made to give you every combination of everything. So I would only use them for that purpose. You will wind up with a mess otherwise.